# Efficient Pairwise jaccard score with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating the jaccard score of two vectors to create a user-item matrix.
The vectors are stored in separate dataframes.

user dataframe is 166 x 1083, it looks like this. Each row contains the vectors of the users

| index | col1 | col2 | ... | col1083 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 165 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

item dataframe is 1083 x 1083, it looks like this. Each row contains the vectors of the items

| index | col1 | col2 | ... | col1083 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1082 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I tried to calculate the jaccard score for each user vector against each item vector using list comprehensions to save the result as a list of lists to be able to store the output in a  dataframe.

```
 jac_score_list = [ [1 - distance.jaccard(user_vectors.loc[user_index], item_vectors.loc[item_index]) for item_index in item_vectors.index ] for user_index in user_vectors.index]
```

Using timeit python module, the process took 114 minutes so it so slow.

Is there an efficient solution for this like how sklearn's pairwise cosine similarity do it in fast and convenient manner like this?

```
user_item_cos_df = cosine_similarity(user_vectors, item_vectors)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances(arr1, arr2, metric="jaccard", n_jobs=-1)`?

Comment: @Chris I just tried it and there's an error  "Dataframe object has no dtype". Currently searching for possible solutions for this. Do you have any insights regarding this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I passed dataframe values instead of df itself. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the comment above, there is already an existing library that can efficiently compute the jaccard for two vectors. The pairwise distances method from the sklearn library can be used.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances 
jaccard = pairwise_distances(arr1, arr2, metric="jaccard", n_jobs=-1)
```

n_jobs is set to -1 which indicates that all processors would be used.

The parameter metric is set to 'jaccard' which computes the *jaccard distances.*

To be able to get the jaccard similarity score, it would be 1 - jaccard distances

```
jaccard_score = 1 - jaccard
```